# How to rephrase these delta epsilon inequalities?

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

When we say that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ can this be restated as $L - \epsilon < f(x) < L+\epsilon$? (removing absolute value to make this easier to understand)

If so I don't know how to restate $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ without the absolute value. because there's a $0 <$ on the end and I don't know how to incorporate it.

I don't think I can ignore the $0$ and just say $c-\delta < x < c+\delta $

Comment: "..and $x \neq c$."

Comment: Is there a way to arrive at that conclusion mathematically from the inequality more formally?

Comment: Yes.  $|x-c|=0$ if and only if $x=c$ and you are disallowing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is equivalent to$$-\varepsilon+L<f(x)<\varepsilon+L.$$

Comment: Typo on my part, I did understand this

Answer (score -1):

By the definition of a limit, you know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in D$ ($x \neq c$) exists $0 < | x - c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Because you know that $\delta > 0$, then you could rewrite $$0 < | x - c| < \delta$$ as $$-\delta < 0 < | x - c| < \delta$$

and from here to get:
$$-\delta < x - c < \delta$$

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. (Try $x=c$.)

Comment: You are right. I forgot to write that. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Still the same error. (The last inequality is satisfied by $x=c$, while the original one isn't.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Is my answer correct / am I missing anything?

Comment: @ArukaJ: More or less, although it seems unnecessarily complicated to me. And after “Rule 2” you should have **or** instead of **and** (and that line also implicitly assumes that $y \ge 0$).